# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un servicio de Android Studio haga lo mismo que un void con muchas variables y que llama a otras actividades?

Tags: java, android

Quiero hacer que un `public void` se ejecute mientras la pantalla esta apagada, por tanto uso un servicio. El problema es que este `void` llama a otros y a variables no estaticas, haciendo asi que el servicio no funcione. ¿Como puedo hacer para que funcione mientras la pantalla esta bloqueada?

Comment: Puedes intentar haciendo un servicio en `Foreground`, y ejecutas tu método desde el servicio. Has intentado algo así?

Comment: No lo he probado, pero es bastante parecido a un servicio normal no? Sigue llamando a elementos del propio servicio o a estaticos de otros java, y para que funcione la accion que quiero, necesita llamar a elementos que no son estaticos.

Comment: si, funciona igual, solo que se queda ejecutando siempre, es como esas apps que mantienen una notificación en el estatus bar, que normalmente son indicación de que algo se esta ejecutando de esa app